# How to make absolute element responsive inside relative

Tags: html, css, position

I've got a problem with making my code work. I've got 2 `divs`, first have `position: relative`, second absolute. What I try to get is the fixed position of `.stamp` `div`, when the screen is more then `max-width: 768px`.

Would love if it would look like this:

[How it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZvmX.png)

In every resolution above 768px.

However, I don't know which units use in right property to make it responsive.

HTML:

```
  <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <h3 class="slider-header">
                    Lorem ipsum<br/>
                    and <strong>ipsum lorem</strong>
                    <div class="stamp">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/80/80"/>
                    </div>
                </h3>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.slider-header .stamp {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 90px;
    right: 26%;
    top: 3rem;
}
.slider-header {
    position: relative;
    text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 2em;
text-align: center;
margin: 40px 0 80px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .subpage .stamp {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        top: 30px;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/zz6r7n4w/10/

Comment: The media query doesn't do anything, because there is nothing with class="subpage".

Comment: fixed media query